# Angular 2 waiting for promise and observable to resolve

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, promise, observable

In my accountService, I have a dialog that asks the user for username/password which returns a promise.  If they click close rather than dismiss and the validators require the data before they can click close, then I want to log in with that data which returns an observable.

```
loginModal() : boolean {

    this.dpDialogService.input(
        'Login',
        [
            {
                label: 'Username/Email', 
                form: 'username', 
                data: '', 
                validators: [Validators.required],
                validatorMsg: 'Username is required.'
            },
            {
                label: 'Password', 
                form: 'password', 
                data: '', 
                validators: [Validators.required],
                validatorMsg: 'Password is required.',
                type: 'password'
            },
        ]
    ).then(
        close => {
            this.login({username: close.username.value, password: close.password.value}).subscribe(
                loginResult => {
                    return true;
                },
                errorResult => {
                    this.dpDialogService.error('Invalid username/password.');
                    return false;
                }
            )
        },
        dismiss => {
            return false;
        }
    );
}
```

How do I return this boolean from the function.  I am guessing I have to use a promise but not sure how with them being nested.

Comment: so, you understand that the code in `.then(close => {` isn't returning anything

Comment: Yes thats what I am trying to figure out, I want a combined result from the nested calls.

Comment: `I want a combined result from the nested calls` - hmmm, not sure what you mean by this ... combined result suggests at least two results becoming one ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `.subscribe` doesn't return a promise, then you need to create a promise that resolves to true/false depending on result of `.subscribe`

I'm assuming the returned promise needs to always resolve, never reject (based on the `dismiss =>` code

```
).then(
    close => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.login({username: close.username.value, password: close.password.value}).subscribe(
                loginResult => {
                    resolve(true);
                },
                errorResult => {
                    this.dpDialogService.error('Invalid username/password.');
                    resolve(false);
                }
            )
        })
    },
    dismiss => {
        return false;
    }
);
```

Comment: sorry, a couple of typos originally

Comment: oh wait ... angualr2 means coffeescript ... my answer may be misleading

Comment: So if the calling function is like this: this.accountService.loginModal(), I want to be able to have this.accountService.loginModal().then(...) and know if they input correct information and was successfully logged in.  So I need a promise returning from the entire function

Comment: Really all I care about is the boolean return, but it has to be a promise to await the two nested async functions correct?

Comment: And I am using typescript

Comment: sorry, I meant typescript, not sure why I wrote coffescript :p

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer, thanks for the help Jaromanda X

```
loginModal() : Promise<boolean> {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.dpDialogService.input(
            'Login',
            [
                {
                    label: 'Username/Email', 
                    form: 'username', 
                    data: '', 
                    validators: [Validators.required],
                    validatorMsg: 'Username is required.'
                },
                {
                    label: 'Password', 
                    form: 'password', 
                    data: '', 
                    validators: [Validators.required],
                    validatorMsg: 'Password is required.',
                    type: 'password'
                },
            ]
        ).then(
            close => {
                this.login({username: close.username.value, password: close.password.value}).subscribe(
                    loginResult => {
                        resolve(true);
                    },
                    errorResult => {
                        this.dpDialogService.error('Invalid username/password.');
                        resolve(false);
                    }
                )
            },
            dismiss => {
                resolve(false);
            }
        );
    });
```